# How to upload files to temporary directory and delete the file if submit button is not clicked?

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I have a form that I want to use uploadify on. I have set the uploadify to upload the files on auto when the file is selected. I want to do something like, upload the file to a temporary directory such that the filename  of the file is saved in the hidden file, and when the user clicks submit, the file is moved to the upload directory. but if the user exits the page or don't click submit, the temporary file should be deleted on the fly.
I am new to uploadify. Seeking some help.

Additional Information:
I have seen a demo of http://dondedeportes.es/uploader-previewer/ . I also wanna know, how it cleans the temporary directory on page exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to upload the file upon selection to your temp directory.  Then if they submit, it also goes to your target directory.  Then just run a job (cron maybe) to clean up the temp directory.  This may be the easiest way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Copy this JS code and replace it with jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min.js

```
     if (jQuery) {
(function (a) {
    a.extend(a.fn, { uploadify: function (b) {
        a(this).each(function () {
            var total = "0";
            var f = a.extend({ id: a(this).attr("id"), uploader: "uploadify.swf", script: "uploadify.php", expressInstall: null, folder: "", height: 30, width: 120, cancelImg: "cancel.png", wmode: "opaque", scriptAccess: "sameDomain", fileDataName: "Filedata", method: "POST", queueSizeLimit: 999, simUploadLimit: 999, queueID: false, displayData: "percentage", removeCompleted: false, onInit: function () { }, onSelect: function () { }, onSelectOnce: function () { }, onQueueFull: function () { }, onCheck: function () { }, onCancel: function () { }, onClearQueue: function () { }, onError: function () { }, onProgress: function () { }, onComplete: function () { }, onAllComplete: function () { } }, b); a(this).data("settings", f); var e = location.pathname; e = e.split("/"); e.pop(); e = e.join("/") + "/"; var g = {}; g.uploadifyID = f.id; g.pagepath = e; if (f.buttonImg) { g.buttonImg = escape(f.buttonImg) } if (f.buttonText) { g.buttonText = escape(f.buttonText) } if (f.rollover) { g.rollover = true } g.script = f.script; g.folder = escape(f.folder); if (f.scriptData) { var h = ""; for (var d in f.scriptData) { h += "&" + d + "=" + f.scriptData[d] } g.scriptData = escape(h.substr(1)) } g.width = f.width; g.height = f.height; g.wmode = f.wmode; g.method = f.method; g.queueSizeLimit = f.queueSizeLimit; g.simUploadLimit = f.simUploadLimit; if (f.hideButton) { g.hideButton = true } if (f.fileDesc) { g.fileDesc = f.fileDesc } if (f.fileExt) { g.fileExt = f.fileExt } if (f.multi) { g.multi = true } if (f.auto) { g.auto = true } if (f.sizeLimit) { g.sizeLimit = f.sizeLimit } if (f.checkScript) { g.checkScript = f.checkScript } if (f.fileDataName) { g.fileDataName = f.fileDataName } if (f.queueID) { g.queueID = f.queueID } if (f.onInit() !== false) { a(this).css("display", "none"); a(this).after('<div id="' + a(this).attr("id") + 'Uploader"></div>'); swfobject.embedSWF(f.uploader, f.id + "Uploader", f.width, f.height, "9.0.24", f.expressInstall, g, { quality: "high", wmode: f.wmode, allowScriptAccess: f.scriptAccess }, {}, function (i) { if (typeof (f.onSWFReady) == "function" && i.success) { f.onSWFReady() } }); if (f.queueID == false) { a("#" + a(this).attr("id") + "Uploader").after('<div id="' + a(this).attr("id") + 'Queue" class="uploadifyQueue"></div>') } else { a("#" + f.queueID).addClass("uploadifyQueue") } } if (typeof (f.onOpen) == "function") { a(this).bind("uploadifyOpen", f.onOpen) } a(this).bind("uploadifySelect", { action: f.onSelect, queueID: f.queueID },
             function (k, i, j) {
                 if (k.data.action(k, i, j) !== false) {
                     var l = Math.round(j.size / 1024 * 100) * 0.01; var m = "KB"; /*if (l > 1000) { l = Math.round(l * 0.001 * 100) * 0.01; m = "MB" }*/
                     var n = l.toString().split("."); if (n.length > 1) { l = n[0] + "." + n[1].substr(0, 2) } else { l = n[0] } if (j.name.length > 100) { fileName = j.name.substr(0, 100) + "..." } else { fileName = j.name } queue = "#" + a(this).attr("id") + "Queue"; if (k.data.queueID) { queue = "#" + k.data.queueID }
                     total = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(l);
                     if (total <= 4000) {
                         a(queue).append('<div id="' + a(this).attr("id") + i + '" class="uploadifyQueueItem" ><div class="cancel"><a href="javascript:jQuery(\'#' + a(this).attr("id") + "').uploadifyCancel('" + i + '\')"><img src="' + f.cancelImg + '" border="0" style="width:18px;height:18px;" /></a></div><span class="fileName">' + fileName + '</span><span class="percentage"></span><div class="uploadifyProgress"><div id="' + a(this).attr("id") + i + 'ProgressBar" class="uploadifyProgressBar"><!--Progress Bar--></div></div></div>')
                     }
                     else {
                         total = parseFloat(total) - parseFloat(l);
                         alert("Total attachment size can not exceed 4Mb.");
                         return;
                     }
                 }
             }); a(this).bind("uploadifySelectOnce", { action: f.onSelectOnce }, function (i, j) { i.data.action(i, j); if (f.auto) { if (f.checkScript) { a(this).uploadifyUpload(null, false) } else { a(this).uploadifyUpload(null, true) } } }); a(this).bind("uploadifyQueueFull", { action: f.onQueueFull }, function (i, j) { if (i.data.action(i, j) !== false) { alert("The queue is full.  The max size is " + j + ".") } }); a(this).bind("uploadifyCheckExist", { action: f.onCheck }, function (n, m, l, k, p) { var j = new Object(); j = l; j.folder = (k.substr(0, 1) == "/") ? k : e + k; if (p) { for (var i in l) { var o = i } } a.post(m, j, function (s) { for (var q in s) { if (n.data.action(n, s, q) !== false) { var r = confirm("Do you want to replace the file " + s[q] + "?"); if (!r) { document.getElementById(a(n.target).attr("id") + "Uploader").cancelFileUpload(q, true, true) } } } if (p) { document.getElementById(a(n.target).attr("id") + "Uploader").startFileUpload(o, true) } else { document.getElementById(a(n.target).attr("id") + "Uploader").startFileUpload(null, true) } }, "json") });
            a(this).bind("uploadifyCancel", { action: f.onCancel }, function (n, j, m, o, i, l) {
                if (n.data.action(n, j, m, o, l) !== false) {
                    $.ajax({ type: "POST",
                        url: "../CommonService.asmx/DeleteFileAttachment",
                        data: "{FileNameTOBeDeleted: '" + (a("#" + a(this).attr("id") + j)[0].innerText) + "'}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json", success: function (data) {
                            if (data.d != 0) {
                                // alert("Deleted Successfully");
                                total = parseFloat(total) - parseFloat(data.d);
                                if (total < 0) { total = 0; }
                            }
                            else if (data.d == 0) {
                                // if not deleted.
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    if (i) { var k = (l == true) ? 0 : 250; a("#" + a(this).attr("id") + j).fadeOut(k, function () { a(this).remove() }) }
                }
            }); a(this).bind("uploadifyClearQueue", { action: f.onClearQueue }, function (k, j) { var i = (f.queueID) ? f.queueID : a(this).attr("id") + "Queue"; if (j) { a("#" + i).find(".uploadifyQueueItem").remove() } if (k.data.action(k, j) !== false) { a("#" + i).find(".uploadifyQueueItem").each(function () { var l = a(".uploadifyQueueItem").index(this); a(this).delay(l * 100).fadeOut(250, function () { a(this).remove() }) }) } }); var c = []; a(this).bind("uploadifyError", { action: f.onError }, function (m, i, l, k) { if (m.data.action(m, i, l, k) !== false) { var j = new Array(i, l, k); c.push(j); a("#" + a(this).attr("id") + i).find(".percentage").text(" - " + k.type + " Error"); a("#" + a(this).attr("id") + i).find(".uploadifyProgress").hide(); a("#" + a(this).attr("id") + i).addClass("uploadifyError") } }); if (typeof (f.onUpload) == "function") { a(this).bind("uploadifyUpload", f.onUpload) } a(this).bind("uploadifyProgress", { action: f.onProgress, toDisplay: f.displayData }, function (k, i, j, l) { if (k.data.action(k, i, j, l) !== false) { a("#" + a(this).attr("id") + i + "ProgressBar").animate({ width: l.percentage + "%" }, 250, function () { if (l.percentage == 100) { a(this).closest(".uploadifyProgress").fadeOut(250, function () { a(this).remove() }) } }); if (k.data.toDisplay == "percentage") { displayData = " - " + l.percentage + "%" } if (k.data.toDisplay == "speed") { displayData = " - " + l.speed + "KB/s" } if (k.data.toDisplay == null) { displayData = " " } a("#" + a(this).attr("id") + i).find(".percentage").text(displayData) } }); a(this).bind("uploadifyComplete", { action: f.onComplete }, function (l, i, k, j, m) { if (l.data.action(l, i, k, unescape(j), m) !== false) { a("#" + a(this).attr("id") + i).find(".percentage").text(" - Completed"); if (f.removeCompleted) { a("#" + a(l.target).attr("id") + i).fadeOut(250, function () { a(this).remove() }) } a("#" + a(l.target).attr("id") + i).addClass("completed") } }); if (typeof (f.onAllComplete) == "function") { a(this).bind("uploadifyAllComplete", { action: f.onAllComplete }, function (i, j) { if (i.data.action(i, j) !== false) { c = [] } }) }
        })
    }, uploadifySettings: function (f, j, c) { var g = false; a(this).each(function () { if (f == "scriptData" && j != null) { if (c) { var i = j } else { var i = a.extend(a(this).data("settings").scriptData, j) } var l = ""; for (var k in i) { l += "&" + k + "=" + i[k] } j = escape(l.substr(1)) } g = document.getElementById(a(this).attr("id") + "Uploader").updateSettings(f, j) }); if (j == null) { if (f == "scriptData") { var b = unescape(g).split("&"); var e = new Object(); for (var d = 0; d < b.length; d++) { var h = b[d].split("="); e[h[0]] = h[1] } g = e } } return g }, uploadifyUpload: function (b, c) { a(this).each(function () { if (!c) { c = false } document.getElementById(a(this).attr("id") + "Uploader").startFileUpload(b, c) }) }, uploadifyCancel: function (b) { a(this).each(function () { document.getElementById(a(this).attr("id") + "Uploader").cancelFileUpload(b, true, true, false) }) }, uploadifyClearQueue: function () { a(this).each(function () { document.getElementById(a(this).attr("id") + "Uploader").clearFileUploadQueue(false) }) }
    })
})(jQuery)};
```

And make this webmethod in CommonService.asmx webservice and remove // from [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]. this mehod delete file store in directory on cancel click

```
     [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public decimal DeleteFileAttachment(string FileNameTOBeDeleted)
    {
        try
        {
        string foldername = Convert.ToString(Session["DestinationPath"]);
            FileNameTOBeDeleted = FileNameTOBeDeleted.Replace("- Completed", "");
            FileNameTOBeDeleted = FileNameTOBeDeleted.Replace("\r\n", "");
            string FilePath = foldername + "\\" + FileNameTOBeDeleted;
            FileInfo FName = new FileInfo(FilePath);
            decimal s1 = FName.Length;
            decimal size = s1 / 1000;
            File.Delete(foldername + "\\" + FileNameTOBeDeleted);
            return size;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

and this on page load where uploadify displayed.

```
         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { if (postedFile != null)
        {
            if (Session["DestinationPath"] == null)
            {
                string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendMail_savepath"];
                string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
                string[] TimeSplit = time.Split(new char[] { ':', ' ' });
                DestinationPath = path + "\\" + AgentId + "_" + DateTime.Today.Day + DateTime.Today.Month + DateTime.Today.Year + "_" + TimeSplit[0] + TimeSplit[1]+TimeSplit[2];

                Directory.CreateDirectory(DestinationPath);
                Session["DestinationPath"] = DestinationPath;
            }
            string AttachedFile = Session["DestinationPath"] + "\\" + postedFile.FileName;
            postedFile.SaveAs(AttachedFile);
        }
    }
```

and this on aspx page

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id$=fuFiles]').uploadify({
        'uploader': '../flashUpload/uploadify.swf',
        'script': '../Utility/CustomerMail.aspx',
        'cancelImg': '../images/cross_icon.png',
        'auto': 'true',
        'multi': 'true',
        'buttonText': 'Add Attachment',
        'queueSizeLimit': 5,
        'simUploadLimit': 1,
        'fileExt': '*.pdf;*.txt;*.doc',
        'fileDesc': 'text Files',
        'sizeLimit': 4194304  // The size limit in bytes for each file upload(5MB).
    });

});
```