# How to get tmp_name in input type='file' using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I get `tmp_name` using jquery?

Can I achieve that using jquery or javascript?

I just want to know, usually in php, we use `$_files['image']['tmp_name']`.
Thanks for your response.

PS : I use the `ajaxForm` plugin.

Comment: I would say NO, not possible!

Comment: what's wrong with these people, i just want to know it is possible or not, why must down vote my question. people come here for learning..ckckck

Comment: surely it depends on which plugin you use as to where it stores the temporary file (if it even creates one), if you are using php to upload the file then why do you need the temp file in jquery? - have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338857/how-to-upload-files-to-temporary-directory-and-delete-the-file-if-submit-button

Answer (score 2):

`$_FILES[...]['tmp_name']` is the path of the temporary location where the file has been stored on the server during/after upload to same. Going by this definition it should be obvious that you cannot get it in Javascript. It does not apply to Javascript. There's nothing you could do with it in Javascript.

You *can* get that path by uploading the file to the server and have the server output that path back to the client in an AJAX request. But what are you going to do with a server-side temporary path on the client side anyway? It's of no use.

Answer (score 0):

This is fundamentally impossible. `tmp_name` is generated server-side, randomly, when your request is submitted. There is no way of finding out in JavaScript which name a server will use *in the future* as the tmp name for a given file.